# My iOS app rejected due to icons are rounded corners

Tags: iphone

Below is the issue:-

**Your app still contains features that mimic the iOS interface. Specifically, 
a portion of your app is characteristic of the iOS springboard, which contains icons with rounded corners in a gridlock-like manner.**

[image: This icon i have used in the app]

Please anyone tell me solution of above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make your icon square without rounded borders.

(And yes Apple is a lovely company respecting the freedom of its developers and not restricting creativity in any way.. )

(Sarcasm)